# wordpress, get category names for a custom post type

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Is there a better way to get the category names for a custom post type in wordpress?

```
<?php        // get the portfolio categories
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'filters' );                           
            if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
                $names = array();
                $slugs = array();
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                 $names[] = $term->name;
                 $slugs[] =  $term->slug;
                }                                
                $name_list = join( " / ", $names );
                $slug_list = join( " category-", $slugs );
        endif;
    ?>


    <!-- BEGIN portfolio-item-->
    <li class="portfolio-item third column category-<?php echo $slug_list; ?>" data-filter="category-<?php echo $slug_list; ?>">
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'filters';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy);

if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Or in fuctions.php place this:

```
  function get_the_category_custompost( $id = false, $tcat = 'category' ) {
    $categories = get_the_terms( $id, $tcat );
    if ( ! $categories )
        $categories = array();

    $categories = array_values( $categories );

    foreach ( array_keys( $categories ) as $key ) {
        _make_cat_compat( $categories[$key] );
    }

    return apply_filters( 'get_the_categories', $categories );
}
```

and call the function as:

```
<?php $cat = get_the_category_custompost($post->ID, 'Your Custom Taxonomy'); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

My answer seems too simple, but I used this to list the categories from a wordpress plugin called [DW Question Answer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dw-question-answer/changelog/) that has separate categories from the standard wp categories.

I am assuming that Design Wall used custom post types to create the q&a part and taxonomies to create the categories.

```
<ul>
  <?php wp_list_categories('taxonomy=dwqa-question_category&hide_empty=0&orderby=id&title_li=');?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your custom taxonomy is recipegroups, i have implemented and tested this code in functions.php and i am sure that it will work in plugins too.

```
$recipeTerms = get_terms(array( 
    'taxonomy' => 'recipegroups',

));
        foreach($recipeTerms as $recipeTerm){
            if($recipeTerm->parent==0){
                echo "<div class='termsBox'>"; // remove these div's to suit your needs..

                $termLink =get_term_link( $recipeTerm );
                echo "<a href='$termLink'><div class='termParent'>".$recipeTerm->name."</div></a>  ";

                $termChilds = get_term_children($recipeTerm->term_id, 'recipegroups' );
                foreach($termChilds as $child){
                    $chTerm = get_term_by( 'id', $child, 'recipegroups');
                    $termLink =get_term_link( $chTerm );
                    echo "<a href='$termLink'><div class='top-cat-items'>".$chTerm->name."</div></a>";
                    }
                    echo "</div>"; // end of termsBox div
                }

            }
```