# Get all category of portfolio in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress. I want to display contact form in footer and in that form i want to put dropdown for categories which are basically my portfolio's categories.

How can i fetch all portfolio category names?

Can anybody answer me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories Would be a good starting point. What have you tried so far?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196719/wordpress-get-category-names-for-a-custom-post-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WP a category (group) is a taxonomy, the taxonomy consists of terms ( single categories ).

The code below collects all portfolio categories and fills an array so you can use it for a `<select>`.

```
    $select_category_arr = array();  
    $taxonomy = 'portfolio_category'; // Go to WPadmin -> Portfolio categories. Check url for correct taxonomy name.
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy
    if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            $select_category_arr[$term->slug] = $term->name;    
        }
    }
```

The array `$select_category_arr` contains all the portfolio categories.