# Get products from category WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using Custom post types, to create 'Products'.

Now, here is the issue.

I am getting all the categories of products using this code:

```
                   <?php echo "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12'>"; ?>
                   <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="hoveris">
                          <div class="overlaytext">
                          <h2 style="color:white;"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h2>
                          </div>
                          <!-- <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'AllProducts'); ?>"> -->
                          <img class="width100" src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>"/>

                        <div class="overlayhoverimage">
                          <div class="option1">
                            <h2 style="color:white;">Test</h2>
                          </div>
                          <br/>
                          <div class="option2">
                            <h2 style="color:white;">Test</h2>

                          </div>
                          <!-- </a> -->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
              <?php echo "</div>"; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which works fine, now I need to be able to list the products inside each category.

For example, I have a category named 'CategoryA'. How do I list all the titles of the products in this category?

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

It needs to be on the same page, what I am trying to achieve, is to get the product name and display it where it says 'Test'

EDIT 2:
This is what I have, so its a custom post type, then categories in this.
[image]

Comment: Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $output = '';
    if($categories){
        foreach($categories as $category) {
          if($category->cat_name=='CategoryA'){
            $output = $category->cat_name;
            //And your code here
          }
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Are you trying this?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the answer,
Unfortunately, this is not working? It just wont display anything at all?

Comment: Still blank? I attached a screenshot that shows my custom post type, in case I have explained it wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196719/wordpress-get-category-names-for-a-custom-post-type

Comment: I already have the categories mate, I just need to display the titles of the products in that category.

I have a feeling your original answer is close?

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to list the posts. Pass the ID or slug of the category as a parameter to this function.